# what is default pin used to pair with a TI sensortag?

Tags: android, sensors

Understand that the `sensortag` is not necessary to really pair it using traditional way, but while I tried to connect to the sensor using standard Bluetooth function in a android phone, it asked for a pin.

Comment: This question is most likely better asked to the vendor's support.

Comment: they don't provide this.

Comment: in that case please provide all relevant information such as part number/serial. Because I can imagine TI making many different types of tags and chances are the pins are unique. (If you have to connect like that in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

PIN 000000 works for pairing CC2541 TI SensorTag with Android 4.4.3.

(PIN 0000 and 1234 did not work)

Pairing with CC2650 SensorTag in Android was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

PIN: 123456 works for CC2640R2F